# How to read text in a PDF

Tags: python, selenium, pdf

I am trying to learn how to read text inside a PDF using the IE driver of Selenium. I am getting a selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with css selector == body

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

TO_url = "Y:\Work\Work\PFCToolbox\exampleTO\HT072663_001.pdf"
vpc_url = "http://dspgot03.vcc.ford.com/apps/vpc/vpc.nsf/"
driver = webdriver.Ie()
driver.get(TO_url)
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body")
time.sleep(10)
```

I also tried using other driver.find_element_by functions but couldn't find one that works

Comment: Do you have an example URL?

Comment: You might want to download the pdf and then use libraries like `pdfrw` to read its content.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding the `body` element, try sending keys to get the text:

```
driver.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
driver.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'c')
```

Then paste it from the clipboard.